# Do redis hashes maintain order of insertion

Tags: redis

Do redis hashes remain the order of key-value pairs they are inserted in? I cannot find anything on this from redis' documentation.

A simple test does say that they remain order but is this ensured? Will this work with cluster or sentinel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NO**, Redis hash doesn't maintain the order. Since it's a hash, it's unordered. If you need to maintain the insertion order, you have do it yourself.

You can use a `LIST` to save the order. Each time you insert an item to hash, also push it to the list. You can wrap these two operations into a transaction or a Lua scripting to make it run automatically.

Comment: You can also use a sorted set to store the insertion times for the hash, which would definitely use more memory than a LIST but makes it easier to update hash values